# Error while running MIT demos

Tags: ros, mit-ros-pkg, hand-interaction

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS gurus,

I've been working on the MIT demo examples for quite a while now. I'm trying to run the hand interaction demo. When I do the following:

```
roslaunch hand_interaction hand_detector.launch
```

I get the following errors in the console:

[Error display](http://piyushchand.blogspot.com/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9757/error-while-running-mit-demos/) by [ros_rocks](https://answers.ros.org/users/436/ros_rocks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_rocks](https://answers.ros.org/users/436/ros_rocks/) on 2011-04-19**:
I am using ubuntu 10.10, Maverick, i am testing the MIT demo on the DIAMOND version of ROS. I dont know what is libusb version, I am considering that this libusb is installed during the installation of the ROS. I think ....this might be the error, how do i install libusb

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-18**:
What operating system are you using? Which distribution and version? Also, the version of libusb might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No idea what makes openni_node crash, but the skel_tracker node crashes because it cannot find the OpenNI configuration XML file that it's trying to load (see line 397 in skeletal_tracker/src/main.cpp).

This probably should be reported to the package maintainer.

**Edit:** I just found this other answer that proposes a solution: http://answers.ros.org/question/688/skeletal_tracker-crashes

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) with karma: 1071 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1